# What kind of questions should be protected?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

I had crossed over 15k reps recently, and SO just gave me the rights to protect/unprotect questions. Now at this moment I wonder which questions should be protected and which one should not be?

While seeing questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery), my instinct says that it should have been protected, since it is a good question with answers more than enough. But it is not protected until now.
When should we decide a question should be protected?

Comment: FWIW: I've not yet needed to protect or unprotect a question.  It's a power that you (and I) have, but it will be used sparingly if at all.  (It may be that I work in … less volatile? … areas of SO where protected questions are a rarity.  But my strong suspicion is that you will seldom find it necessary to use the privilege.  But it is there if it becomes necessary.)

Comment: It is one of the most useless privileges. It sounds cool at first, but you hardly ever need it.

Comment: I used it once, a long time ago. It became almost completely superfluous once [it started happening automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers). That covers just about every case where you'd need to protect.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [Meta Stack Exchange protected FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question):

> #### Why are some questions protected?
>
> Some questions are protected because they are expected to attract either spam or users -- often new users -- who may mistake the site as a traditional forum, posting "noisy" answers such as "Thank you" or "This worked for me" or "I'm also having this problem".

and

> #### When should I protect or unprotect a question?
>
> - Do protect questions that are attracting a lot of non-answers or very poor answers (spam, etc.) from new users.
> - Don’t protect questions just because they’re linked to on a high-traffic news site.
> - Do unprotect questions that aren’t currently attracting a lot of attention and don’t have a long history of unproductive answers.

Only protect questions that need protecting; when they are on the receiving end of a more-than-usual influx of low-quality answers from new users.

Comment: If you don't have protect/unprotect abilities, but find a question that should be unprotected, should you flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: @JonSurrell: If the post matches the criteria from the FAQ and you cannot yourself make the change, using an *other* flag to request that a moderator does it is valid, yes. Do make sure that the question warrants protecting / unprotecting, and explain why in your request.