# How many poor answers should a question attract before it should be protected?

Tags: discussion, support, protected-questions

I just now protected [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825344/217324) on account of it having attracted 3 bad answers, 2 of which were already deleted with the third flagged and attracting downvotes and delete votes. Referencing the guidance [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256203/217324):

> Do protect questions that are attracting a lot of non-answers or very poor answers (spam, etc.) from new users.

What is "a lot" here? Is 3 too small? Is there enough of a pattern of low-rep users posting bad answers here to justify protecting? If not, what should I be looking for? I get the impression this is something that should be done sparingly but I'd like more clarification.

Comment: Definitely not more than 42. I tend to look at the poor answers coming from low rep users. If there is more than 1 deleted answer from a user of less than 10 reputation I protect the question. This doesn't happen very often though.

Comment: 99% of the time I just let the automatic protection on the 3rd deleted answer from a low rep user rule do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

Community ignores answers that are deleted if the user asking them is also removed.

So if a question is attracting spam or nonsense answers such that the answers and the user asking them is getting deleted then you should protect the question to stop that. Here's an [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619801/what-is-the-better-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-delphi) that needed manual protection. Of course you'll need 10K+ to see it in all its gory detail.

Otherwise Community will kick in to protect the question so you only need to manually intervene if the question is attracting poor answers rather quickly.