# Help me understand the cutoff for protecting questions

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, protected-questions

So I just got the 15k Protect Questions privilege, and I'm trying to understand when to use it.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282873/batik-convert-html-css-svg-into-an-image) [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Fys.jpg) appeared in the LQP queue (I'm having this problem too!), and when I went to look at it, I saw that it had a second, equally crappy answer deleted already.

So, I protected it.

Then, I went and found [this blog](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/), which says:

> - Do protect questions that are attracting **a lot** of non-answers or very poor answers (spam, etc.) from new users.
> - Don't protect questions just because they're linked to on a high-traffic news site like Reddit or Ars Technica. While there's certainly some correlation between sudden spikes in popularity and associated non-answers, not all popular questions suffer from this.
> - Do unprotect questions that aren't currently attracting a lot of attention and don't have **a long history** of unproductive answers.

What's the definition of "a lot" and "a long history"? I'm now rethinking my decision to protect it. Are two low quality answers enough?

To clarify: I understand that this is somewhat subjective; that's why it's a user privilege. To me, there's:

1. An unambiguous upper bound. This has been programmed into the Community user.
2. An unambiguous lower bound. Never protect questions below this threshold.
3. A subjective middle ground. Use your judgement.

The question I'm asking is: "What is the line between #2 and #3?"

Comment: It's a judgement call. Most of the questions that need it the most get protected automatically. Personally, if a question is already well answered and I don't see better answer coming in, I'll protect even with just 1 low quality answer from a <10 rep user. That said, there are plenty of questions out there which need a "super-protection" state with a much higher rep as they are magnets for bad answers even from users with >10 rep.

Comment: @Mysticial This question didn't have an answer yet though. So "whether it already has a good answer" is an important component?

Comment: For me yes. But it's a judgement call that doesn't need to be objective. As long as you're not blindly protecting everything, nobody will care. For me, I usually protect with the intention of blocking low-quality copycat or "rep-grab" answers on older popular questions.

Comment: As per your edit, "What's the line?". There's no line. It's a probability curve.

Comment: Two awful ones was always enough for me.

Comment: I am with @Will here - 2 awful answers and I protect. Also note that community protection tends to be [fragile on popular questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242942/165773) with _anomalous_ voting - you may wish to account for that in your personal criteria (I for one do so)

Comment: seems related [How many poor answers should a question attract before it should be protected?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291143/217324)

Comment: Assume you won't need to use it.  At least, I've not found it necessary yet, but it may be that I just work in territory where it isn't often needed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've protected at least 5 questions since I got it. *shrug*. No one has commented to me "why did you protect this?"

Comment: Fine; you must work in different areas from me, then.  That's OK; there often isn't a single answer that fits all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fwiw I did a search for questions with more than 250k views, and also I review LQP and late answers daily. So I kinda put myself out there

Answer (score 13):

If one can come up with hard objective metrics for when to protect a question we could just program it into the automated protection tool.

The whole point of having users with the ability to manually protect/unprotect questions is so that they can use their best judgement as to whether or not they think that the post is likely to continue attract inappropriate answers from new users.

The automated tools will *already* protect a question whose objective stats indicate a very strong possibility of attracting more inappropriate posts from new users.  The ability of you to manually protect items is there for the exceptional cases where you know something that isn't showing up in just the stats of the page.

Comment: Surely there's something at least a *little* less vague than "I know it when I see it", though!

Comment: Can you explain to me how we [didn't just program it into the automated protection tool](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299516/1339987)?

Comment: Inability to describe a signal you're looking for is not the same as inability to data-drive and program a signal.

Answer (score 11):

[This guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) provides a helpful description of what answers are considered troublesome.

It is intended for a bit different use but as far as I can tell, it would be okay to use it when deciding on whether to protect. According to it, you check for answers that:

> - belong to low rep or anon users with no real commitment to the community
> - are *provably* duplicate, that is, were added well after (30+ mins later) other answers that contained the same exact information
> - are short in length
> - do not explain much of anything

I think that if you spot three or more answers that match above (including deleted ones), that would be a fairly solid indication that question may benefit of protection.

Additionally, if you notice that question polluted by these answers is an extremely popular one, consider not only protecting but also bringing it for moderator attention for cleanup (that's actually intended use of the guidance I referred).

When abuse is below that "threshold of three", you better study it more thoroughly and use your judgement to decide. Say, if there are two *qualifying* answers and both are bad enough so that you voted them down, it would be understandable if you additionally protect the question.

Comment: @durron597 two unambigous NAAs. Split by almost 2 months. Question looks like a qualified honeypot if you ask me. If someone unprotects, they better be prepared to explain why they believe that garbage won't come in again, and again, and again (that _judgement_ I mentioned, it cuts both ways - at protection and unprotection)

Comment: This makes more sense. The automatic trigger looks for 3 deleted or 5 total; the human can make the judgment call at 1-4 bad answers that tend to "trickle in".

Comment: @djechlin I think you got it right. Trigger is intentionally made conservative, in order to lower risk of false positives, this is the right approach to automating stuff like that. As a human, you pick it from where automatic check has stopped and use your judgement to decide whether it was too conservative

Comment: Still not convinced we're doing it right. I wonder how many people just randomly protect things because they haven't researched the nuance on how to protect things on meta and it's kinda fun. There might be more human false positives. Also don't think false positives are a big problem for "protecting" so it's not necessarily better than more aggressive automatic + better manual. But I UVed this because you at least have the right explanation for how you're supposed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

> *"What's the definition of "a lot" and "a long history"?"*

Viewed 285 times within 11 month, and 2 upvotes certainly won't fulfill these conditions along the rates questions coming in at the site, and policies are canged IMHO.

Though I have to agree, it's left unclear about what actually are the borderlines for *long history* (I'd say staying around more than a year minimum), or *lots of attention*, where I'd consider something like +1k views.

Comment: Well, of course, those two stats wouldn't be enough to protect, it was the two deleted LQ answers that made me initially decide to do it.