# I can't see an option to protect a question even though I have the privilege to do so

Tags: support, protected-questions

I apparently now have the privilege to protect questions on SO, gained very recently. I can't see where the button is to do this and when I searched, I found explanation of what it means but not how I do it.

For reference I was considering this question should be protected as it is about a fundamental language feature: [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

*Note: I do not think this is a dupe of [Help me understand the cutoff for protecting questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300860). That question is about deciding **when** to protect questions, not about which questions can **be** protected.*

Comment: Ah, I thought it was intended as a preventative measure

Comment: this is not a duplicate indeed (voted reopen). Though I had to re-read three times to get that. Title seems to be somewhat misleading, you'd better mention that _protect_ button is not shown. For a fun trick, in your question example there is an answer from user with 11 rep, that rep is coming from single upvote to that very answer (cast probably as a gratitude of asker). If you vote it down (so that answerers rep falls to 9) and refresh browser, you'll see protect button appearing. (you can retract downvote after experiment is completed during 5 min grace period)

Comment: Thing is when I asked the question I didn't know what button I was looking for ;) It does seem people will automatically vote 'dupe' without actually looking if there is a linked question with similar title.

Comment: _"I was considering this question should be protected as it is about a fundamental language feature"_ - that's not why you should want to protect a question.

Comment: @CodeCaster maybe but every protected question I see matches that description - something fundamental with a huge number of votes and traffic. And that is only a minor point of my question, worthy of a clarification comment not a downvote

Comment: Questions should be protected when they attract a lot of answers from newcomers who want to share their poorly-phrased version of existing answers, nothing more.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Not all questions can be protected.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276978/188189)

Per that answer by [bluefeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/bluefeet)

> 15k users will still be able to protect but in order to do so the question must have at least one answer by a new user aka a user with < 10 rep on the site (which is the required rep limit to answer protected questions).
>
> If the question does not have an answer meeting this requirement, then the protect option will not be available. This should minimize some of the protecting of questions that do not need it.

Moderators can protect any question.

Comment: Also, doesn't the Community user auto-protect questions if 7 non-constructive rookie answers are posted?

Comment: @cst1992 yes but this question is how do **I** protect a question, not when does community do so.

Comment: @cst1992 community auto-protects [when there are 3 deleted answers from new users or 5 answers from new users posted in 24 hours](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299516/839601)

Answer (score 2):

I asked this on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277356/protect-questions-privilege-page-doesnt-mention-the-new-answer-requirement) pointing out that the requirements aren't documented:

> However, I recently went to check for protection and it wasn't
>   available due to the new restriction that [isn't
>   mentioned](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) on
>   the [privilege
>   pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). It
>   took me a few minutes to find the meta.SE question linked. Can the
>   privilege page be updated to reflect the change?

There must be at least 1 deleted answer. [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274324/prevent-protecting-questions-under-certain-circumstances/274328).

There is a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276955/protection-prevention-ignores-deleted-answers-from-new-users) though.